# Open fits file from bz2

Tags: python, fits, astropy

So  I have a compressed fits file which I read like so:

```
File = bz2.BZ2File(fname)
fits = File.read()
```

I'm using astropy.io.fits to read fits files. At the moment I obtain my .fits.bz2 files by api so I would ideally like to be able to read them like `hdulist = fits.open(fit)`

But it just throws up `TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`. ( I have checked that the file is good by unpacking it manually and reading it like above).

I guess my question is a general one: How to pass an open file to another function?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass a string containing the bytes of the file to `fits.open`, which is not the correct usage.  Also, when posting exception messages from Python you should post the full traceback, not just the exception message.  "How to pass an open file to another function?" Like any other variable.  All that matters is that the function in question does anything useful with a file object.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/fits/api/files.html#open) for `astropy` you can find that:

> `astropy.io.fits.open` takes a file name, an open file or a file-like object as it's first argument

You are attempting to pass the contents from the file into `astropy`, rather than the *file object* itself.

To get your example to work you would instead need to just pass the file object returned by `bz2` into astropy which will process it like an uncompressed file.

```
from astropy.io import fits
import bz2

decompressed_file = bz2.BZ2File("example.fits.bz2")
hdulist = fits.open(decompressed_file)
```

Comment: See also this issue I've just opened, as it seems strange that io.fits doesn't support compression in filehandles like it does for files: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/5948